# Moving Python Elements between Lists

Tags: python

```
listA = [1,2,3]
listB = []

print listA
print listB

for i in listA:
        if i >= 2:
                listB.append(i)
                listA.remove(i)
print listA
print listB
```

Why does this only add and remove element "2"?

Also, when I comment out "listA.remove(i)", it works as expected.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should not modify the list you are iterating over, this results in surprising behaviour (because the iterator uses indices internally and those are changed by removing elements). What you can do is to iterate over a *copy* of `listA`:

```
for i in listA[:]:
  if i >= 2:
    listB.append(i)
    listA.remove(i)
```

Example:

```
>>> listA = [1,2,3]
>>> listB = []
>>> for i in listA[:]:
...   if i >= 2:
...     listB.append(i)
...     listA.remove(i)
... 
>>> listA
[1]
>>> listB
[2, 3]
```

However, it's often much cleaner to go the functional way and not modify the original list at all, instead just creating a new list with the values you need. You can use list comprehensions to do that elegantly:

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3]
>>> small = [a for a in lst if a < 2]
>>> big = [a for a in lst if a >= 2]
>>> small
[1]
>>> big
[2, 3]
```

Comment: What you should do is build the output lists that you want, and then perhaps throw away the original (or assign over it) if you no longer need it.

Comment: @Karl: I just added a list comprehension to do exactly that.

Comment: @NiklasB. List comprehension was exactly what I ended up doing, but I wasn't sure why I was getting the problem initially.

Comment: @fluorescentLAMP: Surely worth a question (: If this was helpful, please consider accepting it as an answer!

Comment: @NiklasB. Just did. I had to wait 7 minutes from the original submitting time. You were too quick!

Comment: I think this has to do with how python enumerates/builds references to the items in listA. then when you remove an item these references dont get updated and it runs off the end of the list

Comment: @madmaze: Exactly, as I described in my answer, the iterator that is built at the beginning of the `for` loop remembers it's position inside the list using a numeric index, which is invalidated when modifying the part of the list with indices >= [current iterator position]