# Sorting playing cards

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to sort playing cards. I want to input the cards I have, 2H is 2 of hearts, 3D is 3 of diamonds, etc. And then put the cards in four different lists by suit.  This is just part of my code so far, the problem is when I input multiple cards, only two are moving to the new suit list.

```
cards = [str(x) for x in input().split()]

cards = [A.replace('A', '1') for A in cards] 
cards = [J.replace('J', '11') for J in cards] 
cards = [Q.replace('Q', '12') for Q in cards] 
cards = [K.replace('K', '13') for K in cards] 

hearts = [] 
diamonds = [] 
clubs = [] 
spades = [] 

for i in cards:
    if i in ['1H', '2H', '3H', '4H', '5H']:
         hearts.append(i)
         cards.remove(i)
```

Comment: If you substitute `T` for `10` your life will be a lot easier.

Comment: This is just a condensed version of my code. I'm trying to figure out why it won't append all of the H cards into the hearts list, it only moves two.

Comment: What is the input that you gave?

Comment: For this example I used 4H, 3H, AH, 2H

Comment: I found the answer I was looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9970192

Answer (score 2):

if `4H, 3H, AH, 2H` is your input then you need to split the string with `,`

```
cards = [str(x) for x in input().split(', ')]
```

other wise later in the for loop at this line `if i in ['1H', '2H', '3H', '4H', '5H']:` only the first element in `cards`would return `True` because every element after that has a space and `3H` does not equal `3H`.

Second, This is a big one, don't modify the list you are looping through. do the `cards.remove(i)` after.

```
for i in cards:
    if i in ['1H', '2H', '3H', '4H', '5H']:
      hearts.append(i)

for i in hearts:
  cards.remove(i)

print(cards) #will print []
print(hearts) #will print ['4H', '3H', '1H', '2H']
```