# Filter list of dataframes with another list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two lists of dataframes with identical structures and I'm trying to omit every dataframe from list_a if at least one value from list_a[df_a][col_a] exists in col_a of any list_b dataframes. I've taken several passes at this but haven't found something that really gets it done. My approach might be wrong, point in the right direction is appreciated!

**Approach:**

```
    for df_a in list_a:
        for df_b in list_b:
            temp = df_a[~df_a['col_a'].isin([df_b['col_a']])] # error 'list indices must be integers or slices, not 
            if len(temp.index) > 0:
                list_a.remove(df_a)
```

**list_a[0]**

```
    col_a   temp
877 12/17/2019  0.300807486
886 12/31/2019  0.143508662
```

**list_a[1]**

```
    col_a   temp
651 7/27/2019   0.435680418
660 8/10/2019   0.229333215
```

**list_b[0]**

```
    col_a   temp
1   12/31/2019  0.843356517
10  1/14/2020   0.846720719
```

**list_omit[0]**

```
    col_a   temp
1   12/17/2019  0.600807486
2   12/31/2019  0.143508662
```

**Result:**
As list_a[0] and list_b[0] have overlapping dates of 12/31/2019, list_a[0] should be removed from list_a and added to an 'omitted' list of dfs

**Reproduce:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

temp = list(range(0, 2))
list_a = []
list_b = []

for l in temp:
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(2, 2)), columns=list(['col_a','temp']))
    list_a.append(df)

for l in temp:
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(2, 2)), columns=list(['col_a','temp']))
    list_b.append(df)

print(list_a)
print(list_b)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use modified [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9970192/2901002):

```
np.random.seed(2020)
temp = list(range(0, 2))
list_a = []
list_b = []

for l in temp:
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(3, 2)), columns=list(['col_a','temp']))
    list_a.append(df)

for l in temp:
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,30,size=(2, 2)), columns=list(['col_a','temp']))
    list_b.append(df)

print(list_a)
print(list_b)
```

Create set of all possible values for exclude:

```
b = set([y for x in list_b for y in x['col_a']])
print (b)
{3, 28, 5, 23}
```

Then in loop add to exclude list and also new list of values of `DataFrame`s from `list_a`:

```
exclude = []
a = []
for df_a in list_a:
    if df_a['col_a'].isin(b).any():
        exclude.append(df_a)
    else:
        a.append(df_a)


print (exclude)
[   col_a  temp
0      0     8
1      3     3
2      3     7]

print (a)
[   col_a  temp
0     16     0
1     10     9
2     19    11]
```

Another idea with list comprehensions:

```
exclude = [df_a for df_a in list_a if df_a['col_a'].isin(b).any()]
print (exclude)
[   col_a  temp
0      0     8
1      3     3
2      3     7]

new_a = [df_a for df_a in list_a if not df_a['col_a'].isin(b).any()]
print (new_a)
[   col_a  temp
0     16     0
1     10     9
2     19    11]
```

Comment: First, thank you.. I had been beating my head on the wall trying before posting.
Second, both solution work for the sample provided. However I noticed that when expanding the temp range I get error 'The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()' Any idea how to resolve that?

That said, the second solution with list comprehension works for expanded lists and I suspect this one is going to perform better on larger data sets so I will use this method. Again thank you!

Comment: @Meowbits - hmmm, it seems there is not use `.any()` ? Or possible duplicated columns names?

Comment: removing .any() on the first solution did not resolve the issue. There are definitely duplicate column names between the dataframes though as they all have the same structure.

Comment: @Meowbits - I think if not possible duplicated columns names in one datframe

Comment: column names within a single dataframe are not duplicated. If using the sample code, range(0,3) throws the error in question for solution A

Comment: @Meowbits - So if check linked answer first part then is some internally problem, I try add `list_a[:]` , `list_a.copy()` and failed. solution is create new list, answer is edited in few seconds

Comment: [jezrael] - your update to solution A works by having a separate list :) thank you for the updates