# Iterate through a list of dicts, placing dicts containing a keyword into a new list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dicts in Python called "roles" inside the list the dicts look like this:

```
dict = {"roleName":DisplayName, "accountNumber" : acctNumber} // Info pulled from variables
eg. roles[0] = {"roleName":JSmith, "accountNumber" : 123456}
```

As I'm pulling this info from an API (along with other processing) if any error occurs (no data or failed a sanity check) then instead of the info, this phrase is added

"ERROR: XXXXXXXXXXXX"

so for example: `roles[0] = {"roleName":JSmith, "accountNumber" : "ERROR: NO ID DATA"}`

What I want to do is go through "roles" and pull out (so remove) any dict that contains "ERROR:" in its values and put it into another list of dicts called "errorList"

So roles will have only dicts that dont contain "Error: XXXXXXXX" and errorList will have all dicts that contained "ERROR: XXXXX"

I tried something like this:

```
for i in roles:
       if "ERROR:" in (repr((i.values()))):
            errorList.append(i)
            roles.remove(i)
```

So basically dumping all values in the dict (at role[i]) as a string and looking for "ERROR:". If it had that phrase then it will be appended to another list and removed.

When I had a look at both lists, it seemed like there were some left over dicts (with ERROR:) in them in the original list. I also tried:

```
 for i in roles:
        if "ERROR:" in (repr((i.values()))):
            errorList.append(i)
 for i in roles:
       if "ERROR:" in (repr((i.values()))):
           roles.remove(i)
```

To make two passes, but same result.

What's the best way to do this?

P.S I may have more keys that shown in the example dict, so if possible I would like to avoid checking each key:value pair and just check all values at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was I was working with the original list so it caused unexpected behaviour - [Moving Python Elements between Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970174/moving-python-elements-between-lists)

This worked by using a copy of "roles"

```
for i in roles[:]:
        if "ERROR:" in (repr((i.values()))):
            errorList.append(i)
            roles.remove(i)
```